# Using helper: 'original' with sortable() and draggable() doesn't appear to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have a simple HTML page on which I want to be able to drag the divs numbered 6-10 into the sortable list, which already contains divs numbered 1-5. When I set the draggable helper value to 'clone', this page works perfectly well. However, I want to use the 'original' helper. This doesn't appear to work at all.

Can anyone suggest an alternative? I've tried making "dropTarget" a droppable() area, but that doesn't seem to work. I imagine they are conflicting with each other or something. Any advice would be very welcome!

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <title></title>
  <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.5.1-vsdoc.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.11.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
      $("#dropTarget").sortable({ revert: true });
      $("#itemlist div").draggable({ connectToSortable: "#dropTarget", helper: 'original', revert: 'invalid' });
      $('#itemlist div, #dropTarget').disableSelection();
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="dropTarget" style="width: 100px; min-height: 50px; background-color: Red;">
    <div>Item 1</div>
    <div>Item 2</div>
    <div>Item 3</div>
    <div>Item 4</div>
    <div>Item 5</div>
  </div>
  <div id="itemlist">
    <div>Item 6</div>
    <div>Item 7</div>
    <div>Item 8</div>
    <div>Item 9</div>
    <div>Item 10</div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It seems that you have to give the divs under itemlist a width and height for them to work correcly. The connectToSortable also only really works when the "clone" helper is used (from the documentation - http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Draggable)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have modified your fiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/3wCHu/5/

As jquery documentation says that it not possible to connect to a sortable list when using `helper:"original"`. We can have a workaround.

First thing you can put helper code in your #itemlist as -
`helper: function(ev, ui) { return "<div>" + $(this).text() + "</div>" }`

Secondly, in your #dropTarget code add an option as -
`receive: function(ev, ui){ ui.item.remove() }`
Here ui.item refers to the item that is dragged.